# Unbound Variable in lisp function, I have no clue why

Tags: common-lisp

So im halfway losing my mind over this lisp code im working on. Im not allowed to use most lisp functions so I have to focus on basic commands and recursion. The function is supposed to find the list with the passed matching variable. checkInner works on all my tests, but for some reason asso is throwing an exception "UNBOUND-VARIABLE", if someone could analyze this and explain I would greatly appreciate it. THANKS!

```
(defun checkInner(A L)
    (cond ((and (atom L) (eq A L)) t)
        (t  (cond ((or (atom L) (eq A L)) nil)
                (t (cond ((eq A (car L)) t)
                        (t (checkInner A (cdr L))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
(defun my-assoc(A L)
    (cond ((checkInner A (car L)) (car L))
        ((eq (cdr L) nil) nil)
        (t (my-assoc A (cdr L)))
    )
)


;test cases
(my-assoc 'a nil) ;works
(my-assoc 'a '((a . b)(c e f)(b))) ;works 
(my-assoc 'c '((a . b)(c e f)(b))) ;does not work
```

Comment: I assume you're using Common Lisp.  All three of the test cases work for me in SBCL and ABCL.  Is it possible there's a typo that's present in the code you ran but not in what's entered in the question?  A less likely possibility is that you're using a version of Common Lisp that has a bug.  An even less likely possibility is that your code depends on behavior that is allowed to vary between implementations.  Off the top of my head, I don't see anything I would think would be of that sort, but I don't use CL much and was never an expert.

Comment: By the way, if `my-assoc` is supposed to duplicate the behavior of `assoc`, there's a bug.  Try passing `b`, `e`, or `f` as the first argument.

Comment: ya I know mars, I think the error is at (t (my-assoc A (cdr L))), idk why though

Comment: Maybe there's a parenthesis out of place--not in the code here, but in the code you're running. I prefer to use standard Lisp formatting and indentation (move all of those terminating parens up to the end of the last line of code), with an editor that will automatically indent the code.  If you get used to standard indentation conventions, the auto indenting will tell you where you've have a misplaced parenthesis.  (You also might want to merge those `cond`s in `checkInner` into a single `cond`.  It will make the code clearer, if the problem is there, it might be easier to see.)

Comment: `(cond (x y) (t (cond (w z) ...` can just be `(cond (x y) (w z) ...`.

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: An `unbound-variable` condition has a `cell-error-name`, which states the offending symbol. Your code is probably different from this one, you're probably printing something in between statements; check those expressions for unbound variables.